# How to find the minimum and maximum dates from three tables even if there is no date in one table in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I am having three tables namely trade,advance and loan i want the minimum and maximum dates from these tables even if a table doesn't contains any dates but the query which i am using returns null even if there is no date in that particular table.I want the get the minimum and maximum dates from these three tables

```
SELECT min(mx), max(mn) " +
                "FROM (" +
                "      SELECT min(advancedate) AS mx, max(advancedate) AS mn FROM advancelabel WHERE mobileno = " + farmermobno + " " +
                "      UNION ALL" +
                "      SELECT min(tradedate) AS mx, max(tradedate) AS mn FROM farmertradelabel WHERE mobileno = " + farmermobno + " " +
                "      UNION ALL" +
                "     SELECT min(loandate) AS mx,max(loandate)AS mn FROM loanlabel WHERE mobileno = " + farmermobno + " " +
                "     ) AS t1";
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong in this query.

Comment: do you get any errors with the script provided, or just wrong dates?

Comment: no i didn't get any errors

Comment: then what isn't working properly? you don't get any dates?

Comment: @abbath instead of using union all can use inner join,yes i am not getting any dates if there is no date in one table even if there are dates in other table

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the script if it is working already?

Comment: @abbath it doens't shows the minimum and maximum dates even if there is no date in one table

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this screnshot when no record available in any table.

http://prnt.sc/cy7bti

check this screenshot for min,max date from database

http://prnt.sc/cy7cdm

query is like simple same like as your query.

```
select min(mindate),max(maxdate) from (select max(date1) as maxdate,min(date1) as mindate from table1 union all select max(date2) as maxdate,min(date2) as mindate from table2)
```